# Problem with updating blob, if blob contains specific data

Tags: delphi, blob

I have binary data that needs to be stored in a BLOB field in a SQL-database.
In case of an UPDATE (storing into the database), the binary data comes as a string (BDS2006, no unicode).
When the BLOB field is READ, the binary data needs to be returned as a string.
Therefore, I have used these two pieces of code (qry is a TQuery):

READ:

```
var s: string;
begin
  qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT BlobField FROM Table WHERE ID=xxx';
  qry.Open;
  if qry.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      qry.First;
      s := qry.FieldByName('BlobField').AsString;
    end;
end;
```

UPDATE:

```
var s: string;
begin
  s := ...binary data...
  qry.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE Table Set BlobField=:blobparam WHERE ID=xxx';
  qry.ParamByName('blobparam').AsBlob = s;
  qry.ExecSQL;
end;
```

I'm not sure if that's the right/good/ok way to do it, but it has worked fine for a couple of years.

Now there is a problem with a specific set of binary data, which after being UPDATE'd into the database and then READ from the database is changed/corrupted.
When comparing the param value before ExecSQL with the value of s after reading, the last byte of data (in this case 1519 bytes total), is changed from 02h to 00h.

Since I am not sure if my code works correctly, I have tried to use TBlobStream, to check if the results change.

READ:

```
var s: string;
    bs: TStream;
    st: TStringStream;
begin
  qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT BlobField FROM Table WHERE ID=xxx';
  qry.Open;
  if qry.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      qry.First;
      st := TStringStream.Create('');
      bs := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName('BlobField'), bmRead);
      bs.Position := 0;
      st.CopyFrom(bs, bs.Size);
      st.Position := 0;
      s := st.ReadString(st.Size);
    end;
end;
```

UPDATE:

```
var s: string;
    bs: TStream;
    st: TStringStream;
begin
  s := ...binary data...
  st := TStringStream.Create(s);
  st.Position := 0;
  qry.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE Table Set BlobField=:blobparam WHERE ID=xxx';
  qry.ParamByName('blobparam').LoadFromStream(st, ftBlob);
  qry.ExecSQL;
end;
```

The result is the same, the last byte of the read data is corrupted.

What could be my problem?

---

**EDIT:**

Using only streams produces the same problem.

I found that this only happens if the data is exactly 1519 bytes. Then, and only then, the last byte is set to 0, no matter what it was before. Of course there might be other cases for the problem, but that's one that I can reproduce every time.

If I add one more byte to the end, making it 1520 bytes, everything works fine.
I just don't see anything special here that could cause it.

Comment: Has any changes/patches been installed in the Server OS or Database Software?

Comment: No, I just take the executable that was running for some time, and feed it with that particular binary data, and it comes back from the database changed. I tried with several version that were done during the past years, all behave the same.
If it breaks with one set of data, it's generally broken. I am sure it's not the database itself, it should be something in my code, some of the conversions maybe. I just can't see it.

Comment: Sorry, no to the database server changes, too. It's an embedded database engine, which makes it just my executable to depend on.

Comment: The trailing NULL (00h) makes it look like some kind of buffer size problem, something passed though a PChar (C string). 5EFh / 5F0 seem strange sizes though.

Comment: It's only Pascal strings and TParams, so there should not be a problem like this.
If the way I'm doing this is correct, there might be another cause. I'm just not sure if I do anything bad here that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: Can you store it as a binary stream and only convert once retrieved and convert to binary when you store again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gerry that the trailing NULL looks like a string problem.

Your modified code still writes the data using TStringStream. Have you tried writing the data using a TBlobStream, and seeing if that makes a difference?

Alternatively, add some packing bytes at the end of the problem data, to check if it is related to a specific size/boundary issue. Or try replacing the problem data with a fixed test pattern, to narrow the problem down.

FWIW I have used blobs without problem for a long time, but have never treated them as strings.

Good luck narrowing the issue down.

UPDATE: looks to me like your code is fine, but you are running into somebody else's bug somewhere in the database/data access software. What database/driver/access code are you using?

Comment: The problem was database related, thanks for all the suggestions that helped to get to the cause.